# Iogear USB KVM - Windows 10 - loses mouse, keyboard when switching

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, kvm-switch

I have a DELL PowerEdge running Windows 10 (upgraded) attached to an Iogear GCS24U 4-port USB KVM. Sometimes when I am switched to another computer, when I switch back the keyboard and mouse are "frozen". The only recovery seems to be to hold the power button in, triggering a "hard" reboot. When this happens, I am able to switch to other (Win7) devices and the KB and mouse work continue to work normally.

I have set the Root USB power management setting to NOT power down. IIRC that seemed to solve the problem back when the computer was Windows 7, but it is happening again since the Win10 upgrade. (I have rechecked the setting.)

Are there other settings or other ways to prevent this from happening?

Are there ways (i.e., commands) that could be triggered from a remote desktop or remotely via an "AT" job (from another computer on my LAN) to reset/restore the keyboard and mouse to the KVM?

Thanks very much.